# How to encode XML to base64 and then save it to stream?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, encode

The task is to send a `HTTP` `web request` along with `Soap Envelope` that must be converted to  `base64`.

Unfortunately, I cannot convert the `Envelope` to `base64` because my method `InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest` uses the `XML` and saves it to `stream` as below. I need to follow this structure for the request to work.

```
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(attachmentName);
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(url, action, attachmentName);
    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

    private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope(string attachmentName)
    {
        //Convert name to base64
        var fileNameEncoded = EncodeStringToBase64(attachmentName);
        var authorizationIdEncoded = EncodeStringToBase64("C61582-B73K47EJ54");
        var authorizationKeyEncoded = EncodeStringToBase64("TWTXBP-HNEZ9J-74EV8Z-QM5J9T");
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml($@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" xmlns:ns4=""https://efaktura.bg/soap/""><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns4:uploadFile><ns4:authorizationId>{authorizationIdEncoded}</ns4:authorizationId><ns4:authorizationKey>{authorizationKeyEncoded}</ns4:authorizationKey><ns4:fileName>{fileNameEncoded}</ns4:fileName></ns4:uploadFile></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
    //            doc.LoadXml(soapRequest.ToString());
        return soapEnvelopeDocument;
    }
    public static string EncodeStringToBase64(string plainTextBytes)
    {
        var plainText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextBytes);

        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainText);
    }

    private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to convert the `XML` to `String` but in `CreateSoapEnvelope` I have a method `LoadXML` and if it is `base64` , the method cannot read it because it is not in `XML` format.

If I do the conversion in `InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest` then I am unable to use `soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream)`

Where and how can I do the conversion?

Comment: could you write `soapEnvelopeXml` to a `MemoryStream`, and then use `Convert.ToBase64String` on the `MemoryStream` contents (`ToArray()`, or `GetBuffer()` **plus** `.Length` - `GetBuffer()` is oversized)

Comment: You need a "body" tag in the XML which contains the base64 string.

Comment: @jdweng I want the whole SOAP to be converted to base64, not just insert it in the body and paste it along.

Marc I really did not understood your answer. I tried but I could not write an xml to  a memory string?

Comment: A request has required xml tags.   If you want the entire SOAP base64 you then you have to send the mase64 not as a SOAP but use another method like send the data using TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your InsertSoapEnvelope method to this:

```
    private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            soapEnvelopeXml.WriteTo(tx);

            string str = sw.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(soapEnvelopeXml.ToString());
            ASCIIEncoding Encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var arr = Encode.GetBytes(EncodeStringToBase64(str));
            stream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        }
    }
```

If you `Console.Writeline` the `XML.ToString()` it will give you the reference. The idea is to write the `XML` to a `TextWriter` which uses a `StringWriter`. Once you done this you have to `encode` it first and then convert it to a `byte array`. The it is just a matter of writing it to the stream. you give the array,  0 offset and the length of the byte array as parameters.